# How to trap read write system calls?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, system-calls

Whenever i attempt to write anything on my pendrive, a write system call is generated. What i want to do is, this write call should be trapped and and the user should be requested to input predecided password( which i can define during coding itself).
Please tell me whether this is possible or not? and if yes than how should i do it?

Answer (score 2):

The windows DDK has an example of hooking the file reads/writes/copies in `filesys\minifilter`, with both pre and post op callbacks, that should have you set for the kernel side of things. For the gui part you'll need something to do a non-blocking spin till the drives signals an event, you'll probably also want a pipe or mapped memory view to pass data around

Answer (score 0):

[EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) is supposed to give you the ability to hook kernel functions. I have not tried it, so your mileage may vary. Be sure to hook functions cautiously - you may degrade the performance of your machine to a point where it's unusable. What you want is to interact with the user, meaning that you must put the hooked function on hold, and issue a callback into user space. This is probably not an exercise for mere mortals.

At any rate, good luck!